# Unable to get the new Message received on the device

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have created an application which gets all the message from the inbox into the application.
I have written a broadcast receiver which calls the My activity but , when the activity is started the sms in not been shown inside my Inbox Fragments which pulls all the sms from the inbox.

Here is the code of broadcast reciever.

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        // final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

And code for the MainActivity.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new InboxFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SentMsgFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new DraftsFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



}
```

So when the application restarts it should display the new sms but it doesnt, is their any other way to show the new received sms in the application as soon as it is received.

Comment: you need check if activity is running just refresh data inside of activity instead of start that,

Answer (score 0):

> register reciever dynamically so that you can have flexibility in UI
>   updating the  activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private IncomingSms incommingSms;
        onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        ...
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        intentFilter.setPriority(100);
        incommingSms=new IncomingSms.class); 
        registerReciever(incommingSms,intentFilter);
        .....
        }
        onDestroy(){
        ...
        unRegisterReciever(messagereceiver);
        ....
        }
        public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
                Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] objects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    if (objects != null) {
                        SmsMessage message = SmsMessage
                                .createFromPdu((byte[]) objects[0]);
                        if (message != null) {
                           // update UI in your activity
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
     }
```